# How to remove dynamic text in middle from a sentence

Tags: javascript, string, validation, split

I have one requirement where the sentence string is "Shivkumar Pending Fund Changes 202164172551.xlsx is ready"

Note- date value is dynamic in nature the format of date is - yyyymdHHMMss

Do let me know how i can slice second from the string in JavaScript.

Comment: so last 2 digits of `202164172551` will always be second?

Comment: @rajdeep yes it will be always a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = "Shivkumar Pending Fund Changes 202164172551.xlsx is ready"

let modifiedStr = str.replace(/\d{2}.xlsx/g, ".xlsx");;

console.log(modifiedStr);
```

Comment: Returning a integer number , my input is
"Shivkumar Pending Fund Changes 202164172551.xlsx is ready" and output I'm expecting 
"Shivkumar Pending Fund Changes 2021641725.xlsx is ready"

Comment: @ShivkumarDubey here you go

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = "Shivkumar Pending Fund Changes 202164172551.xlsx is ready";
s = s.split(".xlsx")[0];
console.log(s.substring(s.length - 2, s.length));
```

Comment: I'm getting empty value